# Filter ArrayList after converting a Long (from the constructors) to a String

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this Long values stored in the database as a DATETIME, I have a problem regarding on how to filter these records based on the date required, the date and time was stored as a Long value. I query the records by this code

```
public List<DatabaseSource> getListSched() {
 List<DatabaseSource> taskList = new ArrayList<DatabaseSource>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM schedTBL" ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            DatabaseSource tasks = new DatabaseSource();
            tasks.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            tasks.setSubject(cursor.getString(1));
            tasks.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            tasks.setDueDateTime(cursor.getLong(3));
            // Adding contact to list
            taskList.add(tasks);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    // return contact list
    return taskList;
}
```

My constructor

```
public DatabaseSource(int id, String subject, String description, Long dueDateTime) {

        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.description = description;
        this.dueDateTime = dueDateTime;
    }
```

Now, when I try to convert the values from the getDueDateTime (Long) to a date to a string, it works to display exactly as date and time. After converting them, I want to filter the records based on the date string (which comes from the sharedpref). The flow of my layout is, after selecting the day from the calendar the next activity shows the filtered records which has similar dates but different time. 
Here's how I display the records in a listview

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreferenceUID();
    text = sharedPreference.getValue2(mContext);
    String dateString= DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a", new Date(mSchedLists.get(position).getDueDateTime())).toString();
    View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_listview, null);
    TextView subj = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtSubject);
    TextView duedate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDueDateTime);
    subj.setText(mSchedLists.get(position).getSubject());
    duedate.setText(dateString);
    v.setTag( mSchedLists.get(position).getId());
    return v;
}
```

As you can see the date and time are successfully converted but it displays all the records, I only want to display the records with same date after comparing it to a saved date in the sharedpref regardless the time. Assume you clicked a date from the calendar and that date was saved to sharedpref and the next activity already filtered the records based on the date clicked from the previous activity.

[image: ListView]

Comment: you should use the Long value for filtering, not the string.

Comment: you don't get it, I stored date and time values as Long in the database so how am I suppose to query that based only the date saved in the sharedpref and there's no time included in sharedpref?so meaning in the database I saved it as a long (numerical conversion of date and time). If it is possible to filter it and send it to another arraylist how can I do that?

Comment: Any reason you cannot store the date value as long in SharedPreference. If you can do that then it may be easier for you to filter out the data.

Comment: I can but the problem is the value of date as long is different from the value of date and time as long :) so I needed to convert the values of the date and time to string from the arraylist and trying to find a solution to filter them by comparing a date string to them.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your problem, you want to filter your records according to a specified date, For this.
First of all, format your db date values with the same date format as you have in shared prefs, let's assume you are using MM/dd/yyyy format.
Then, you will have dates according to the same format, then use (Date Obj)date.getTime() method(which returns millisecs) now compare these millisecs(of your shared prefs date) with the millisecs(of your db date) basically the check would be on Date Object and not string, if the above matches, which means the date is same, now you can filter your records according to it.
(For converting your string to Date obj. just use its Constructor and pass the string to it).